# How I Can fix more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I tired so much things about this error but I couldn't fix it.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 10
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comping `google play service library`, but in your gradle file, have some libraries depend on  this lib. So having you error **more than one library with package**. First, you check your libs dir which lib contains `google play service library`, if having you no need to compile `compile project(':google-play-services_lib')`. I think the best way you can follow https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup to setup exactly google play service.